# Declaring Size of Array Using Variable

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma warning (disable : 4996)

void main() {

    int matrix[30][50];

    int sizeRow, sizeCol;

    printf("Number of Rows in your table    : ");
    scanf("%d", &sizeRow);

    printf("Number of Columns in your table : ");
    scanf("%d", &sizeCol);

    int sum[sizeRow] = { 0 };

    for (int row = 0; row < sizeRow; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < sizeCol; col++){
            printf("Input element [%d][%d] : ", row, col);
            scanf("%d", &matrix[row][col]);
            sum[row] += matrix[row][col];
        }
    }

    printf("Total of each row:\n");
    for (int row = 0; row < sizeRow; row++){
        printf("ROW[%d] SUM :\t%d\n", row, sum[row]);
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

I am getting error in the `int sum[sizeRow] = { 0 };` where it says that my array should be a constant but the user in my case should determine the array size. Any way I can fix this?

Comment: The program works if I input an integer instead of sizeRow btw.

Comment: You would need support for C99 _variable length arrays_ (VLA — or C11 and an implementation that doesn't define `__STDC_NO_VLA__`).  AFAIK, MS Visual Studio still doesn't support them.  GCC and Clang do.

Comment: Makes sense since I am using VS. Let me try CodeBlocks

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Even if he will use GCC with c99 option on, he will get the same error message. Initializer list can't be used with VLA; *The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.*-§6.7.9-p(3)

Comment: @haccks: Actually, that's a different error message ("cannot initialize a VLA" is different from "dimension of an array must be a constant").  But you're right; once the OP gets past the current error, he will encounter the one you mention.

Answer (score 6):

MSVC doesn't support variable length arrays.  You'll need to allocate memory with `calloc`.  Unlike `malloc`, `calloc` initializes all bytes to 0:

```
int *sum = calloc(sizeRow, sizeof(int));
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory afterward.

Comment: So then how do I initialize my sum to 0?

Answer (score 4):

I have just noticed that you are using MSVC. Nowadays, it is possible to use VLAs with it. Since Visual Studio 2015, it [almost] fully implements C99, but still treats all C99 features as language extensions (e.g. disabling language extensions disables C99 support as well). *As a result, you either use prior version or disabled some extensions.* Moreover, on the next step, you most likely encounter with the message that *variable-sized object may not be initialized.*

> The following example
>   demonstrates how to use C99 Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) in a
>   `firstprivate` directive ([Section 2.7.2.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d179faxw.aspx) on page 26). Source: [MS Developer Network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb1574zs.aspx)

```
void f(int m, int C[m][m])  
{  
    double v1[m];  
    ...  
    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(C, v1)  
    ...  
}
```

---

> Assuming your "problem" is that the compiler objects, if you're using
>   GCC or Clang, try adding the flag `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` to your
>   command line. GCC defaults to an older version of the C language that
>   doesn't have this functionality.
>
> You don't need malloc unless you intend to return the array. Always
>   use the simplest thing that will work.

Comment: The last quote is wrong, GCC has for long defaulted to an extension standard that has supported VLAs.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length gnu90 supports VLAs and the default standard used to be gnu90, not c90.

Answer (score 2):

`int sum[sizeRow]`  declares a variable length array which is introduced in C99 and older versions of MSVC does not support VLAs.
Also note that one of the restriction on VLA is that it can't be initialized with initializer list and therefore the  line

```
int sum[sizeRow] = { 0 };
```

will raise an error message even if you compile with a compiler that does support VLA.

§6.7.9-p(3):

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete object type that is not a variable length array type.

Either use `memset`

```
int sum[sizeRow];  
memset(sum, 0, sizeof(sum));
```

or a `for` loop to initialize it

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++)
    sum[i] = 0;
```

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thanks. It is added in vs15.

Answer (score 0):

You should include a #define directive to set the array rows and columns then make the user to input them, like this:

```
#define ROWCOL
#define COLUMNCOL
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Answer] paqges before long.  Why would a `#define` with no value be useful?  How would you use them?

Comment: and moreover, the user will determine the size of my col and row, so define is useless?